# change css variables based on values in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, css, heredoc

I have a css file heredoc as php with 3 values defined

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");
$clabel = '#384DA0';
$cbackground = '#89A1BA';
$cfont = '#000000';
?>
```

I want to change these variables based on values in the mysql tables. yet retain the default value if no such value exists.

How would I go about doing that?

Thak

Answer (score 0):

Set them before using the heredoc:

```
$request = //do some database request here;
$clabel = $request['clabel'] ? $request['clabel'] : 'default value';
$myCSS = <<<EOT
      .someclass{color: $clabel;}
EOT;
```

According to my (rudimentary) knowlege of heredocs, your css should be parsed with the variables assigned properly.

Comment: I'm new to this, but i have a table called template and there is column called colorlabel. how do i get that value? it is not letting my execute php code as the content type is css

Comment: Executing your code before you send your headers should work, let me know if not.